# Filter missing row numbers

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I have a tibble with 61.998 rows but the document ID goes from 1:62.000. Now I want to find out the number of the documents which are missing because I need this both numbers for merge my dataset with an other. How can I filter this out with tidyverse?

```
my_tibble%>%
filter(document %in% 1:62000)
```

The code above don´t work for my purpose. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what field indicates in your `my_tibble` row numbers?

Comment: Sorry I edit my post to make my problem more clear.

Comment: Have a look at the `setdiff()` function. `setdiff(1:62000,df$document)`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a "not in" operator like this:

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

and then go with:

```
my_tibble%>%
filter(document %notin% 1:62000)
```